# Hadoop - Multiple input and join between these input files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I want to use Hadoop on multiple files (actually 2 files) as a input files.

For example:

**File input 1:**

```
user1 italy
user2 spain
user3 italy
...
```

**File input 2:**

```
user1 trackname1
user2 trackname2
user3 trackname1
...
```

I need the number of users per country, then for each country the most popular tracks in (file 2). And finally the number of occurrences of the most popular tracks.

I Would like to have as **outputs**, something like:

```
Popular track (italy):
trackname1 (occurrences)

Popular track (spain):
trackname2

...
```

Actually i've tried to use 2 mappers and 1 reducer. But I don't know how to make the "join" between the two input files on the user field. What could be the best solution for that?

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you 're going to need a chain of three jobs (maybe I use too many jobs, but this will give you the intuition and you can later optimize it):

- **Job 1** (the join)

  - **Map of file1** 
    output *key*: userid
    output *value*: country (you can put a special prefix to know it's a country and not a track)
  - **Map of file2** 
    output *key*: userid 
    output *value*: track
  - **Reduce** (userid, < country, track >) 
    output *key*: (country-track) 
    output *value*: 1
- **Job 2** (the counting)

  - **Map**: Identity Mapper
  - **Reduce** (country-track, < 1,1,1,... >)
     
    sum up the 1's for each (country-track)
    output *key*: country 
    output *value*: (track, count) pair
- **Job 3** (the sorting)

  - **Map**: Identity Mapper
  - **Reduce** 
     
    keep from the values the track with the maximum count and output: 
    output *key:* country 
    output *value:* track

Jobs 2 and 3 can use a combiner, similar (but not identical) to their reducer. I repeat that this is not the best solution and much can be done to optimize it (especially Jobs 2 and 3). For example, you could output from Job 1 a country as a key and a (track, 1) as a value and then finish at Job 2.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

two questions: What do you mean with "Identify Mapper"? How can i pass the output of Job 1 to Job 2 and so on?

Comment: If this is one of your first MapReduce programs, perhaps you should start with more typical (1-job) programs. Moving on to your questions: An Identity Mapper, is one that does nothing! It simply forwards its input to the reduce phase. So, you don't have to implement it, just set as Map class `IdentityMapper.class`. Then, to "chain" two MapReduce jobs, I recommend reading this post: https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining . A simple case, however, is to just put as input of one job the output folder of the other. A tricky part can be the Input & Output Format.

Comment: But if i'm gonna use a IdentityMapper.class, how the Reducer (of the job 2, for example) can read the job 1 output? Maybe i gotta specify this "temp" input (that's the output for the job 1) in the Driver class? That's tricky, and i didn't find anything on the web..

Comment: Yes, specify as input in the Driver class of job 2, the output path of job 1. See the tutorial that I sent you